# Better Paginator - a userscript to add a page-number-box to the paginator

Tags: script, tampermonkey

## Better Paginator

<kbd>[Install](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/se-userscripts/raw/main/better-paginator/better-paginator.user.js)</kbd>

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

The code is in [this file on GitHub](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/se-userscripts/blob/main/better-paginator/better-paginator.user.js).

### About

This script adds a box to the paginator where you can type in a page number (i.e., on the Questions page), press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then it will take you to the page number you specified.

The user [Goku カカロット](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1288675/) suggested a feature that does this in [this MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385699/for-paginated-results-add-a-way-to-type-the-page-number-to-which-to-navigate). As far as I know, this isn't an official feature currently, so I wrote a userscript that does that.

#### License

This userscript is under the MIT license.

#### Download

<kbd>[Install](https://github.com/CoconutMacaroon/se-userscripts/raw/main/better-paginator/better-paginator.user.js)</kbd>

#### Platform

I typically write these on Windows in either Firefox or a Chromium-based browser with Tampermonkey installed. Other userscript managers may work, but I don't test with other ones.

### Contact

I made this. The easiest way to contact me is to [ping me in Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/525173/cocomac), but feel free to leave a comment/answer here, or file an issue on the GitHub repo that my userscripts are in.

### Code

I wrote this in JavaScript, I have a repo on GitHub where I keep the userscripts I wrote. Feel free to send a PR there if you want.

Comment: I would recommend injecting CSS to style the element, rather than using inline styles, especially since you're already assigning the new element an ID (which makes selecting it using CSS trivial).